# Identify, and compare, two rows in two different tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N2RkB/1/).
My setup has the following two tables: `simTable = datatable-simf-sim` and `resTable = datatable-simf-res`.

I am trying to add a row into `resTable` everytime the user selects (clicks) on a row in `simTable`, this works great. However when the user deselects the row, it should be removed from `simTable`.

```
resTable = $('#datatable-simf-res').dataTable({});
simTable = $('#datatable-simf-sim').dataTable({});

$('#datatable-simf-sim tr').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('row_selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
        var uniqueid = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(0)').text();

        $('#datatable-simf-res tr td').each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() === uniqueid) {
                var rowindex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
                resTable.fnDeleteRow(rowindex);
            }
        });

    } else {
        $(this).addClass('row_selected');

        var rows = [];
        $(this).closest('tr').find("td").each(function (cell, v) {
            rows.push($(this).text());
        });
        resTable.fnAddData(rows);
    }
    resTable.fnDraw();
});
```

When you play with the jsfiddle (just click a bunch of times on the rows) you will see that it will leave rows untouched, or removes the wrong rows. I am assuming is has to do with the way I identify a row in `resTable`, as this was the biggest bottleneck for me.

So how do I succesfully identify, and compare, two rows in two different tables?
Thank you very much.

Comment: The fiddle seems to work fine for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the fiddle seems fine to me, a cleaner way to remove the row would be:

```
// iterate over rows, not all cells
$('#datatable-simf-res tr')
  .filter(function () {
    // check if the first column contains the unique ID
    return $(this).find('td:first').text() === uniqueid
  })
  .each(function () {
    // 'this' is the current DOM element, inside .each()
    resTable.fnDeleteRow(this)
  });
```

(The [DataTables API](http://datatables.net/api) says that `fnDeleteRow` accepts either an index or a `<tr>` element.)

Comment: Thank you. My original method shows inconsistent results in Firefox, yours works great and looks a lot cleaner. Thanks!